# place panel in rectangle with screen coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get a panel to use the same coordinates of the points of a rectangle I plot?
For example, say I  plot the points of a rectangle with

```
SetCursorPos(200, 200); // top left
SetCursorPos(200, 400); // top right
SetCursorPos(400, 400); // bottom right
SetCursorPos(200, 400); // bottom left
SetCursorPos(300, 300); // center
```

Then I create a panel, and give it the same dimensions

```
panel.Size = new Size(200, 200);
```

Now I  want to position the panel exactly in the location of the rectangle.

This is where I am having problems.
I have been trying unsuccessfully to accomplish this.
I tried...

```
Control control = panel;
Point point control.PointToClient(new Point(200 + 8, 200 + 32)); // the additions make up for the fact that PointToClient and PointToScreen are out by those pixels
```

This shows the correct coordinates for the panel when I position it.

```
panel.Location = new Point(point.X, point.Y);
```

> Before : Location point 0,0
>
> After :
>
> (0)  top left - 200,200
>
> (1)  center - 300,300
>
> Location point 200,200
>
> Rect: (200, 200)-(400, 400)  Size: {Width=200, Height=200}

The panel however, is always offset, regardless.

[image]

I tried moving the anchor point, but this does not help.

```
panel.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top);
```

...and I also tried

```
ClientToScreen(panel.Handle, ref point);
```

...to no avail.

Could the problem be associated with the parent's (Form) relative position? What do I need to do to  simply reposition the panel so that it aligns with my rectangle?

Comment: You set the Point to the Panel Client area. You need the Panel's Parent (the Form). Anchors are irrelevant. -- *the additions make up for the fact that PointToClient and PointToScreen are out by those pixels*: what? -- If your app is run in a machine with a High-Dpi monitor, your app needs to be DpiAware, otherwise you get wrong coordinates anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. That helped.

Comment: Hi @Jimi, I have spent a day trying to get this work with another panel. Thinking I must be making the mistake of doing something different, I used the same code from the previous panel, and it doesn't do the same thing, but is offset. Why might that be?

Comment: A different parent? I have no way to verify your setup.

Comment: The same parent. I am only trying to place second panel alongside the first panel. Both on the same parent (form). So in my image, the first panel fits the rectangle. The second panel is also given a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way that gets what I want.
I use the parent's top left, and subtract it from the child's top left I want to place. Then use the resulting value for the position.

```
panel.Location = new Point(panel.Left - parent.Left, panel.Top - parent.Top);
```

This way, I always know the objects position, relative to its parent.

Results

[image]

Edited :
I give Jimi's suggestion another try, and it does work. (The problem was with my coordinates.)

```
Control control = form; // not panel
Point point control.PointToClient(new Point(200, 200)); 
panel.Location = point;
```

Thanks again Jimi.